# Perl Module fails install with CPAN/cpanm

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, cpan

I am trying to install some perl modules which are dependencies for a program I want to install (MEME-suite).
Running "perl dependencies.pl gives me the following:

```
Checking Required Perl Modules:
HTML::PullParser missing.
HTML::Template missing.
HTML::TreeBuilder missing.
XML::Simple missing. On Ubuntu, you may need to first run 'sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev'
XML::Parser::Expat missing.

Checking Optional Modules:
Log::Log4perl missing. Used for logging and debugging by developers.
Math::CDF missing. Only required for fasta-enriched-center script (which is not called by the web scripts).
XML::Compile::SOAP11 missing. Used for downloading sequence databases from RSAT.
On Ubuntu, you may first need to run 'sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev'
XML::Compile::WSDL11 missing. Used for downloading sequence databases from RSAT
XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP missing. Used for downloading sequence databases from RSAT
```

However, when i try and install the perl modules i am missing using: either "cpan HTML::PullParser" or "cpanm HTML::PullParser" i get a failure message and the following data log:

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7044 on perl 5.026002 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
Work directory is /home/weilii/.cpanm/work/1541617377.2551
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have /usr/bin/wget
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.29
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching HTML::PullParser () on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on HTML::PullParser
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking HTML-Parser-3.72.tar.gz
Entering HTML-Parser-3.72
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.58 ... Yes (7.24)
Configuring HTML-Parser-3.72
Running Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for HTML::Parser
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have XSLoader 0 ... Yes (0.27)
Checking if you have HTML::Tagset 3 ... Yes (3.20)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.24)
Building and testing HTML-Parser-3.72
cp Parser.pm blib/lib/HTML/Parser.pm
cp lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/TokeParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm blib/lib/HTML/LinkExtor.pm
cp lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/HeadParser.pm
cp lib/HTML/Filter.pm blib/lib/HTML/Filter.pm
cp lib/HTML/Entities.pm blib/lib/HTML/Entities.pm
cp lib/HTML/PullParser.pm blib/lib/HTML/PullParser.pm
Running Mkbootstrap for Parser ()
chmod 644 "Parser.bs"
"/home/weilii/miniconda3/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Parser.bs blib/arch/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.bs 644
"/home/weilii/miniconda3/bin/perl" "/home/weilii/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/home/weilii/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/home/weilii/.cpanm/work/1541617377.2551/HTML-Parser-3.72/typemap'  Parser.xs > Parser.xsc
mv Parser.xsc Parser.c
"/home/weilii/miniconda3/bin/perl" mkhctype >hctype.h
"/home/weilii/miniconda3/bin/perl" mkpfunc >pfunc.h
/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc -c   -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.72\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.72\" -fPIC --sysroot=/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot "-I/home/weilii/miniconda3/lib/5.26.2/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"  -DMARKED_SECTION Parser.c
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
Makefile:357: recipe for target 'Parser.o' failed
make: *** [Parser.o] Error 127
-> FAIL Installing HTML::PullParser failed. See /home/weilii/.cpanm/work/1541617377.2551/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
```

I cannot seem to get this, or a few other dependencies of MEME to install.
I am VERY new to linux and my searching of this and various other forums has not led me to any solutions.

I have tried this using "sudo cpan HTML::PullParser" and when i do it that way it claims that "HTML::PullParser is up to date (3.57)." but it is still listed as not installed when i run "perl dependencies.pl" to check dependencies for MEME.

I also have miniconda installed, and believe the issue may have something do do with cpan pointing to my system perl installation, while MEME is checking for dependencies in the miniconda installation?

Any help getting these modules installed so I can get MEME installed would be very helpful, as I need the program for my research and have been banging my head into this wall for weeks, and my advisor is starting to get flustered with me.

I feel very lost on how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the perl you're using.

The module you're trying to install contains parts written in C. To compile these, perl invokes the same C compiler it was compiled with itself. That is, the path to the C compiler was set when perl itself was configured (and then compiled).

Your perl is trying to use a C compiler of `/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc`, which looks like a temporary build path, not something that would be present on your own system.

You can also see that the perl being used is `/home/weilii/miniconda3/bin/perl`, not the system perl (which probably has a working C compiler configuration).

Presumably this is the "miniconda" thing you mentioned. It's installed in your home directory and lists itself in your `PATH` before the system directories, so perl is found there first. By doing `sudo cpan ...` you're running `cpan` as root (which does not have your `PATH` settings), so it finds the system perl, which not only has a working C compiler but also a completely different set of installed modules.

That is, `HTML::PullParser` is installed in your system perl ("up to date"), but when you run perl as your normal user, the miniconda perl is executed, which has a different set of module directories (and a broken C compiler configuration).

I know nothing about miniconda. The way I would attempt to fix things from a perl perspective is:

- Never use `sudo cpan`. Installing new modules (or upgrading old modules) in system directories is a bad idea.
- Decide which perl to use. The miniconda perl looks broken, so that's out. Our choices are 1) the system perl or 2) a custom perl in our home directory (easily installed via [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/)).
- If a custom perl: Plain `cpan HTML::PullParser` (or any other module) should just work fine. It will install everything under `~/perl5/perlbrew`.
- If the system perl: set up [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib#SYNOPSIS). This consists of two parts:

  - Install `local::lib`. Usually there's a system package for it (e.g. with Debian `apt-get install liblocal-lib-perl` should work).
  - Add `eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib)"` to your `.bashrc` and start a new shell.

  Now plain `cpan HTML::PullParser` (or any other module) should just work.

In any case you'll have to remove `~/miniconda3/bin` from your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the logs you have provided i can see two missing dependencies mentioned in your first block.

```
sudo apt-get install libexpat-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

These appear to be required and running the above will confirm they are present.

In the second block i notice

```
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
```

which indicates you are missing `gcc`

Ubuntu provides a bunch of prebuilt packages that contain the fundamental tools needed to build from source , `gcc` included. See https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/build-essential for the full list.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Once the above is installed, give the Perl installed another go and that should do the trick.

Comment: Could i please get a reason for the down vote so i can amend my answer and improve? Thanks

Comment: `/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gcc` is a path under `/tmp`. There's no way a system package will provide that file.

Comment: The error is from trying to install HTML::PullParser, which does not require expat or libxml2.

Comment: So trying those commands didnt seem to accomplish anything. 

"Note, selecting 'libexpat1-dev' instead of 'libexpat-dev'
libexpat1-dev is already the newest version (2.2.5-3)." and

"E: Unable to locate package libxm12-dev"
and
"build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
build-essential set to manually installed."




As far as the downvote, it was not me so idk.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem. The path `/tmp/build/80754af9/perl_1527832170752/_build_env/bin/` indeed looks weird, and we would not expect the gcc binary file to be placed here. 
According to this [discussion](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10690#issuecomment-468489937) the problem is with the default version of perl on Conda-forge having the hardcoded path to the compiler. The @luvaul hack is to use other healthy perl version like this:
`conda install -c conda-forge perl=5.26.2=h470a237_0`
In my situation it solved the issue. Unfortunately, it has been at least a year, and this issue is still not resolved for all.